# Update a column taking data from same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and data looks like this I want to fill the dates eg:-1-5 should have date 2/8/2012 and 6-9 should have dates :- 8-Feb

```
1   2/8/2012    G8-212
2   null            G8 711
3   null            G8-719
4   null            G8 331
5   null            G8 320
6   8-Feb           G8 172
7   null            G8 606
8   null            G8 176
9   null            G8 372
```

End result should be something like this

```
1   2/8/2012    G8-212
2   2/8/2012    G8 711
3   2/8/2012    G8-719
4   2/8/2012    G8 331
5   2/8/2012    G8 320
6   8-Feb           G8 172
7   8-Feb           G8 606
8   8-Feb           G8 176
9   8-Feb           G8 372
```

Comment: Not without some sort of sort order. How do you know that 2-5 follow 1?

Comment: What is the type of first column, should be VARCHAR, then you can cast the same using dateformat, but the command depends on SQL Engine you are using. Share the server name (mysql or oracle or etc.).

Comment: I am Using Oracle and data type of 1,2 &3  column is Int , varchar() , varchar().i can change the data type if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select 
  id, 
  nvl(date_column,last_value(date_column ignore nulls) over (order by id)) as date_col, 
  code
from your_table
order by id;
```

see a [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8731)

Answer (score 1):

Please try using merge:

```
merge into YourTable a
using (
    SELECT ID,
    ColumnName,
    nvl(ColumnName,last_value(ColumnName ignore nulls) over (order by ID)) as ColumnName_A
  FROM YourTable 
  ) b
on  (a.ID = b.ID)
when matched then 
  update set a.ColumnName = NVL(b.ColumnName, b.ColumnName_A)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try doing something like this, assuming you are sorting on the first column:
(NOTE: I'm not familiar with the Oracle/PLSQL syntax, so take these queries with a grain of salt.)

First, you need to get all the indexes of the non-null rows and their value:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1
WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
```

Now, loop through the results of this query and update the column as needed:

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR v_cols IS
          SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL;
     Int previousIndex := 0;
BEGIN
     FOR v_col IN v_cols LOOP
          UPDATE col2
          SET col2 = v_col.col2
          WHERE col1 < v_col.col1 AND col1 > previousIndex;
          previousIndex := v_col.col1;
     END LOOP;
END;
```

This is obviously untested, so let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks For answering but using (last value) Analytic Function will do the job fine..i am going to try this code and let u know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! I never used nvl before, so I learned something too haha.